# Express Sequelize Error - Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have successfully connected Sequelize and Express using Sequelize's github example with a few changes. I am now trying to do a simple Sequelize query to test the connection, but continue to receive an error stating that the model I have queried is not defined.

```
// ./models/index.js
...
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres'
});
// Test SEQUELIZE connection
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

```
// ./routes/index.js
const models = require('../models');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/contacts', (req, res) => {
    models.Contact.findAll().then(contacts => {
        console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(contacts, null, 4));
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

```
// ./models/contact.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var Model = Sequelize.Model;

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Contact extends Model {}
    Contact.init({
      // attributes
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    }, {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'contact'
      // options
    });
    return Contact;
};
```

The error I am getting when using postman to hit `/contacts` with a GET request is:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
The server is now running on port 3000!
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Database connection has been established successfully.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
    at router.get (C:\Users\username\desktop\metropolis\metropolis-backend\routes\index.js:6:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not requiring the model properly.
In `./routes/index.js` add the next line:

```
const Contact = require('./models/contact.js');
```

And then call `Contact.findAll()...`

Second approach:

You can gather all your models by importing them into a loader.js file which you will store in the models directory. The whole job of this module is to import the modules together to the same place and then export them from a single place.
It will look something like that:

```
// loader.js
const modelA = require('./modelA');
const modelB = require('./modelB');
const modelC = require('./modelC');
...

module.exports = {
 modelA,
 modelB,
 modelC,
 ...
}
```

And then you can require it in the following way:

in `router/index.js`:

```
const Models = require('./models');
const contact = Models.Contact;
```

Comment: I tried your above method and then the error changes to ```TypeError: Contact.findAll is not a function```.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue though by changing ```models.Contact.findAll...``` in the routes file to ```models.contact.findAll...```. The models/index.js file seem to be loading the models, but its doing so based on the FILENAME which is all lowercase.

Comment: Last thing...What I don't understand though is in the github example [here](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example), they use lowercase model file names, but use titlecase model names in their routes file. Shouldn't they have the same problem I am having?

Comment: The file's name is with lowercase but if you look into the model's definition you'll see that it is defined with uppercase. look here: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js